# Is there a way to retrieve a list of document IDs from a collection in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I've been researching efficient ways to retrieve data and one way is to set up what's basically a batch read (not sure if this is possible) from a list of document IDs.

I can probably store the document IDs in a field with an array, but curious if getting the list of document IDs (not all of the data within them) is possible in the Javascript library. I see it's possible with the REST API but so far I'm just using the client SDK so not sure I want to get started adding that.

For reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/list

Answer (score 3):

There is no API for any mobile client SDK to get a list of just document IDs.  You will have to query the entire collection and load all the documents.